# How to make pdflatex work with custom TEXMFHOME and TEXMFVAR paths?

Tags: pdftex, texlive, texmf

Here is my code:

```
% foo.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
\faAdjust
\end{document}
```

I have installed [basictex](http://www.tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html) on Mac, so compiling the above document would fail with this expected error:

```
$ pdflatex foo.tex
...
! LaTeX Error: File `fontawesome.sty' not found.
...
```

Now I am trying to setup my own personal user-tree at an arbitrary location and compile this document. Here is what I tried.

```
rm -rf texmf texmf-var ~/Library/texlive # Cleanup remnants of previous trials
TEXMFHOME=texmf tlmgr init-usertree
TEXMFHOME=texmf tlmgr --usermode install fontawesome
```

This installs `fontawesome` into `texmf` directory but it also tries to execute `updmap` which fails with this error:

```
$ TEXMFHOME=texmf tlmgr --usermode install fontawesome
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.mirror.ac.za/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
[1/1, ??:??/??:??] install: fontawesome [270k]
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
running updmap ...

tlmgr: updmap failed (status 1), output:
updmap [ERROR]: Either -sys or -user mode is required.
updmap [ERROR]: In nearly all cases you should use updmap -sys.
updmap [ERROR]: For special cases see http://tug.org/texlive/scripts-sys-user.html

tlmgr: package log updated: texmf/web2c/tlmgr.log
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

So I now ran `updmap` manually.

```
TEXMFVAR=texmf-var updmap-user
```

This successfully generates the map files in `texmf-var` directory. At this stage this is how the `texmf` and `texmf-var` folders look like:

```
$ find texmf -type f
texmf/tex/latex/fontawesome/ufontawesomethree.fd
texmf/tex/latex/fontawesome/ufontawesometwo.fd
texmf/tex/latex/fontawesome/ufontawesomeone.fd
texmf/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesomesymbols-generic.tex
texmf/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesome.sty
texmf/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesomesymbols-pdftex.tex
texmf/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesomesymbols-xeluatex.tex
texmf/web2c/tlmgr.log
texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
texmf/fonts/tfm/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome--fontawesomeone.tfm
texmf/fonts/tfm/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome--fontawesomethree.tfm
texmf/fonts/tfm/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome--fontawesometwo.tfm
texmf/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome.otf
texmf/fonts/type1/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome.pfb
texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/fontawesome/fontawesomeone.enc
texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/fontawesome/fontawesomethree.enc
texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/fontawesome/fontawesometwo.enc
texmf/fonts/map/dvips/fontawesome/fontawesome.map
texmf/tlpkg/tlpobj/fontawesome.tlpobj
texmf/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb

$ find texmf-var -type f
texmf-var/web2c/updmap.log
texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex_dl14.map
texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex_ndl14.map
texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap/kanjix.map
texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/ps2pk.map
texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/download35.map
texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/psfonts_t1.map
texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/psfonts_pk.map
texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/builtin35.map
```

Now I try to compile my pdflatex again but it fails:

```
$ TEXMFHOME=texmf TEXMFVAR=texmf-var pdflatex foo.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./foo.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 2
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 22 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(texmf/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesome.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(texmf/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesomesymbols-generic.tex)
(texmf/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesomesymbols-pdftex.tex)) (./foo.aux)
(texmf/tex/latex/fontawesome/ufontawesomeone.fd) [1{texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/u
pdmap/pdftex.map}] (./foo.aux)
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 FontAwesome--fontawesomeone
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for FontAwesome--fontawesomeone.
mktexpk: perhaps FontAwesome--fontawesomeone is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
 )
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file FontAwesome--fontawesomeone): Font FontAwesome--f
ontawesomeone at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

How can I compile this file with custom `TEXMFHOME` and `TEXMFVAR` paths?

Comment: Why on earth aren't you installing texlive-full to avoid that hassle?

Comment: @KeksDose I have `texlive-full` too on a different system where everything works fine. In fact `texlive-full` is not necessary to resolve this. Merely installing the package with `--usermode` but without custom `TEXMFHOME` and `TEXMFVAR` or installing it without `--usermode` option is sufficient to resolve this. It is only when I use `--usemode`, custom `TEXMFHOME`, and custom `TEXMFVAR` together that I have this issue and I want to understand the cause of this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Short Answer

The command `TEXMFVAR=texmf-var updmap-user` should be `TEXMFHOME=texmf TEXMFVAR=texmf-var updmap-user` instead. The `TEXMFHOME` path needs to be specified so that `updmap-user` reads the font map config from the user directory, finds an entry for `fontawesome` in it and includes details about it in the map files generated at the `TEXMFVAR` path.

See point 5 in the detailed answer below for more details about this.

#### Detailed Answer

I am writing this detailed answer for the sake of completeness, so that anyone who wishes to set up a user tree to install fonts can just follow these instructions step by step.

**Caution:** Note that I recursively forcibly remove the `texmf` and `texmf-var` directories below in step 2, so that I can start a clean user environment and clearly show the files that get installed in the usertree directories.  However, you might want to skip step 2 if you do not want to lose your existing usertree directories.

1. Here is the source code file:

   ```tex
   % foo.tex
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{fontawesome}
   \begin{document}
   \faAdjust
   \end{document}
   ```
2. Start with a clean user environment:

   ```sh
   rm -rf texmf texmf-var
   ```

   **Caution:** Read the note above this list.
3. Create the user tree:

   ```sh
   TEXMFHOME=texmf tlmgr init-usertree
   ```

   At this point, the user tree looks like this:

   ```
   $ tree -F texmf/
   texmf/
   ├── tlpkg/
   │   ├── texlive.tlpdb
   │   └── tlpobj/
   └── web2c/

   3 directories, 1 file
   ```
4. Install `fontawesome` into the user tree:

   ```sh
   TEXMFHOME=texmf tlmgr --usermode install fontawesome
   ```

   When this command is run, the following error occurs:

   ```
   tlmgr: updmap failed (status 1), output:
   updmap [ERROR]: Either -sys or -user mode is required.
   updmap [ERROR]: In nearly all cases you should use updmap -sys.
   updmap [ERROR]: For special cases see http://tug.org/texlive/scripts-sys-user.html
   ```

   Despite the above error, `fontawesome` is fetched successfully. The user tree looks like this:

   ```
   $ tree -F texmf
   texmf
   ├── fonts/
   │   ├── enc/
   │   │   └── dvips/
   │   │       └── fontawesome/
   │   │           ├── fontawesomeone.enc
   │   │           ├── fontawesomethree.enc
   │   │           └── fontawesometwo.enc
   │   ├── map/
   │   │   └── dvips/
   │   │       └── fontawesome/
   │   │           └── fontawesome.map
   │   ├── opentype/
   │   │   └── public/
   │   │       └── fontawesome/
   │   │           └── FontAwesome.otf
   │   ├── tfm/
   │   │   └── public/
   │   │       └── fontawesome/
   │   │           ├── FontAwesome--fontawesomeone.tfm
   │   │           ├── FontAwesome--fontawesomethree.tfm
   │   │           └── FontAwesome--fontawesometwo.tfm
   │   └── type1/
   │       └── public/
   │           └── fontawesome/
   │               └── FontAwesome.pfb
   ├── tex/
   │   └── latex/
   │       └── fontawesome/
   │           ├── fontawesome.sty
   │           ├── fontawesomesymbols-generic.tex
   │           ├── fontawesomesymbols-pdftex.tex
   │           ├── fontawesomesymbols-xeluatex.tex
   │           ├── ufontawesomeone.fd
   │           ├── ufontawesomethree.fd
   │           └── ufontawesometwo.fd
   ├── tlpkg/
   │   ├── texlive.tlpdb
   │   └── tlpobj/
   │       └── fontawesome.tlpobj
   └── web2c/
       ├── tlmgr.log
       └── updmap.cfg

   22 directories, 20 files
   ```

   The `texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg` contains the font map configuration:

   ```
   $ cat texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
   # Generated by /Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr on Sun Aug 18 14:21:53 2019
   Map fontawesome.map
   ```
5. Run `updmap-user`:

   ```sh
   TEXMFHOME=texmf TEXMFVAR=texmf-var updmap-user
   ```

   Note that it is necessary to specify `TEXMFHOME=texmf` in the above command so that `updmap-user` reads `texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg` (i.e., the font map config file in the user tree). If we do not do so, then the map files generated in `texmf-var` would not contain details about `fontawesome`.
6. Finally, run `pdflatex` to generate the output PDF:

   ```sh
   TEXMFHOME=texmf TEXMFVAR=texmf-var pdflatex foo.tex
   ```

   Alternatively, this also works:

   ```sh
   TEXMFHOME=texmf:texmf-var pdflatex foo.tex
   ```

   The `pdflatex` command needs to know about both `texmf` (for the fonts) and `texmf-var` (for the font maps), that's why we need to specify both directories in the above commands.

#### Summary

Here are all the commands once again for convenience:

```sh
TEXMFHOME=texmf tlmgr init-usertree
TEXMFHOME=texmf tlmgr --usermode install fontawesome
TEXMFHOME=texmf TEXMFVAR=texmf-var updmap-user
TEXMFHOME=texmf TEXMFVAR=texmf-var pdflatex foo.tex
```

Comment: Telling people to recursively forcibly remove directories without any warning or caveats is liable to cause unhappiness. Telling people to use `updmap-user` is likely to further it. Really, this is the way of woe.

Comment: @cfr Good point. Thanks! I have added a warning now that explains why I remove the usertree directories in my steps and why the reader might want to avoid that. The requirement for `updmap-user`, however, comes from the original question. As a result, my answer also ends up using `updmap-user`. If there is a way to solve the problem posed in the question without using `updmap-user`, a new answer to this question would be very welcome.