# Error when installing fonts with tlmgr

Tags: texlive, tlmgr

I tried running the command `tlmgr install libertine` to install a font. This gives me the following error:

```
tlmgr: updmap failed (status 1), output:
updmap [ERROR]: Either -sys or -user mode is required.
updmap [ERROR]: In nearly all cases you should use updmap -sys.
updmap [ERROR]: For special cases see http://tug.org/texlive/scripts-sys-user.html

tlmgr: package log updated: /home/roger/texmf/web2c/tlmgr.log
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

The only post I could find about this error was [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449278/how-to-make-pdflatex-work-with-custom-texmfhome-and-texmfvar-paths). That allowed me to install the font correctly. However, I would like to be able to install font packages in the future using the command `tlmgr install <package>`.

Is there any way I can configure tlmgr to call udpmap-sys or udpmap-usr so that I can install packages with tlmgr without having to run any extra commands?

Comment: You might want to mention which texlive you are using, upstream texlive 2019  or from a Linux distribution? As the latter changes tlmgr

Comment: I am using TeX Live 2017/Debian. This was installed on Ubuntu 18.04 with Apt.

Comment: Hmm, I would have thought you would get an error because tlmgr cannot update a texlive 2017 with data for texlive 2019, it will normally complain quite loudly. But I haven't used Debian texlive in years I always use upstream. You might want to drop using tlmgr and see if you can install the Debian packed Deb of that texlive font. No idea what it us called, you might want to install and use apt-file to look for libertine.sty (Debian packs upstream texlive into a plethora of Debian packages that are very hard to keep track of)

Comment: I set tlmgr to use an archived repository of 2017 packages. I was hoping to get tlmgr working to install fonts.

Comment: Basically, I need to get tlmgr to call "updmap-sys" or "updmap-uuser" instead of "updmap."

Or I need to get "updmap" to automatically work in sys or user mode rather than just print out "updmap [ERROR]: Either -sys or -user mode is required."

Comment: I wouldn't bother with old versions. Waste of time might even be errors in the packages archived, mistakes do happen

Comment: Updmap was rewritten around that point

Comment: Installing an entirely new version of Texlive just to be able to install fonts seems like a bit much. The install works fine if I run updmap-sys after installing the font with tlmgr. I just want to get tlmgr to call updmap-sys instead of updmap.

Comment: you get all the upgrades, I see it as a waste of time staying on old versions trying to hacked them to get them to work. Again why not just installing that font via apt?

Comment: I am not aware of any upgrades I need. I still use TeXLive 2015 on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine and that suits my needs perfectly well. tlmgr installs fonts perfectly because updmap just runs without needing the -sys or -user arguments. 

I don't like to have any programs on my computer that aren't managed by apt. Apt will only install TexLive 2017 on Ubuntu 18.04 with default PPAs, so that's what I plan to stick with unless there is a feature I am missing. 

I would like to get tlmgr working to install fonts, in case some are not available from apt.

Comment: Make sure to read https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i if you are thinking of installing into a user tree or with the user option.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra
```

This is a hugely bloated package of different fonts including libertine. But if you like installing soft by `apt`, it might be easier to just install 400 MB package and save some time.